# Accessing Multipolygon Coordinates from a GeoJson In Rust

Tags: rust, coordinates, geojson

I am trying to access some polygon coordinates from a GeoJson in Rust. I have managed to get the file to load, iterate over the features and identify a multipolygon. Now I would like to extract the polygon coordinates.

Below is an abbreviated version of code so far and results achieved. As you can see the coordinates are right there but I just don't know how to get to them directly (other than parsing as a string). Any insights into how to access the actual x and y would be appreciated! I am sure they are just in a tuple or vector but my limited Rust knowledge is holding me back.

This is the code:

```
use std::collections::hash_map::Iter;
use std::io;
use geo::{coord, geometry, Polygon, MultiPolygon};
use shapefile;
use geojson::{Feature, GeoJson, Geometry, Value, FeatureCollection, };
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use std::fs::{File, read_to_string};
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn main() {
    let geojson_filename: &str = "C:\\Users\\grego\\Documents\\Rust\\tryout\\Data\\ATP2052.geojson";
    let geojson_str: String = std::fs::read_to_string(geojson_filename).unwrap();
    let geojson = geojson_str.parse::<GeoJson>().unwrap();
    let features = FeatureCollection::try_from(geojson).unwrap();

    for feature in features{
        
        for geom in feature.geometry{
                     
            let test = {geom};
                       
            println!("{:?}", test.value);
        }
        
}
}
```

This is what is returned by the above code. The coordinates are right there but appear to be buried in some kind of multilayer tuple or array. Any advice on how to get to them would be appreciated!

MultiPolygon([[[[757595.1587689654, 7066523.236528132], [757408.90407467, 7057288.369063497], [745785.7220177042, 7057517.6071314495], [745856.9156787053, 7061211.386303112], [749178.3553552193, 7061147.084633836], [749286.4302862699, 7066687.645368515], [757595.1587689654, 7066523.236528132]]]])

Comment: You should take a look at the docs. `test.value` is of type [`Value`](https://docs.rs/geojson/latest/geojson/enum.Value.html), and the `MultiPolygon` variant essentially has the type `Vec<Vec<Vec<Vec<f64>>>>`. You can extract the variant data by matching as usual, and the use iteration or indexing to access the data in the vector.

Comment: Thanks, I have this sorted now. It's taken me a while to get my head around the whole enum thing in Rust but now I get it.